# How do I configure eslint-plugin-jsdoc to disallow '*' and 'any' while using minimal set of rules?

Tags: javascript, eslint, jsdoc, eslintrc, eslint-plugin-jsdoc

I'm trying to set `preferredTypes` to prevent `*` or `any` as param/property types. I don't want to use most of the recommended rules as it flags up *too* many issues. I'm trying to ease my team onto using this lint rule set, and gradually fix issues and switch rules on later.

I thought preventing `@param {*}` would be easily done [as per the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc#user-content-eslint-plugin-jsdoc-settings-settings-to-configure-check-types-and-no-undefined-types):

> `settings.jsdoc.preferredTypes` An option map to indicate preferred or forbidden types (if default types are indicated here, these will have precedence over the default recommendations for check-types).

So my `.eslintrc.js` settings object looks like:

```js
...
settings: {
  ...
  jsdoc: { preferredTypes: { '*': false } }
}
```

And I have the rules 'jsdoc/valid-types', 'jsdoc/no-undefined-types', and 'jsdoc/check-tag-names' (picked as a balance of flagging bigger errors but not too many right now).

But I'm not seeing any reporting of errors on `@param {*}`.

Can this be done without adding extra jsdoc lint rules, or if it does need them can I customise it to it only hits `{*}` or `{any}`?

Answer (score 1):

### At minimum you need `jsdoc/check-types`

This rule is referenced in the documentation for `check-types` and this rule is required, even though it's not explicit under the documentation for `preferredTypes`.

Here is the excerpt burried part way down the [`check-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsdoc#user-content-eslint-plugin-jsdoc-rules-check-types) examples:

```js
/**
 * @param {*} baz
 */
function qux(baz) {
}
// Settings: {"jsdoc":{"preferredTypes":{"*":false,"abc":"Abc","string":"Str"}}}
// Message: Invalid JSDoc @param "baz" type "*".
```

Without `check-types` the preferred types setting does nothing, which, if you think about it makes sense.